# R - Check dimensions of database object using duckdb and arrow

Tags: r, dbplyr, duckdb

I am new to working with databases and have been taking an approach that uses packages {duckdb}, {arrow} and {dbplyr}. I am doing some joins and would like to know the number of rows of the csv files I am working with. E.g.:

```
db1 <- arrow::open_dataset(source = paste0(path, "data1.csv"), format = "csv") %>%
   arrow::to_duckdb()

db2 <- arrow::open_dataset(source = paste0(path, "data2.csv"), format = "csv") %>%
   arrow::to_duckdb()

innerjoin_data <- inner_join(bd1, bd2, by = "id") %>%
   collect()
```

Now, how do I get the number of rows of the respective csv of db1 and db2? How do you do the diagnostics to check how many did not match and why, when working with large datasets that you would rather not load in the machine (as in this case)?

Comment: `nrow(innerjoin_data)`? as well, `nrow(open_dataset(...))` (no `duckdb`) will tell you the original number of rows for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @r2evans suggests, R has an `nrow` function for this purpose. This is the standard option when working with data in memory. However, it may not work on remote/database tables as expected.

Hence, if you want to do this starting from your current setup, I would use `ungroup` and `summarise` as follows:

```r
db1 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(num = n())
```

And repeat for `db2` and `innerjoin_data`.

This is the dbplyr equivalent of the common SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
FROM db1
```

Comment: this is it! thanks a lot, I could have never gotten there myself